# how to set jdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true globally

Tags: java, java-9

I am trying to move one of our systems from java 8 to java 9 and about one third of the unit tests that worked OK in java 8 fails with the error below:

```
java.io.IOException: Can not attach to current VM
```

Google took me to a few pages and I quickly understood that in java 9 the default behavior was changed to prevent attaching to the current VM and to go back to the old way you need to set the system property `jdk.attach.allowAttachSelf` to true.

When setting this in IntelliJ the tests work fine. The same works when changing build.gradle to include this:

```
test {
    jvmArgs '-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true'
}
```

However, I would rather prefer to have this setting globally so I don't need to hack my build.gradle and IntelliJ.

I am running java 9 on ubuntu and I changed `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh` to include this:

```
export JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true"
```

When running my Gradle build I can see the setting being picked up because I am getting below in the build output:

```
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
```

However, the tests keep failing with the same IOException.

So what I am doing wrong and how should I fix it?

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Incredible. 2 YEARS, and not even something understandable from official sources.

Comment: If someone still has this problem, make sure you test with `--no-daemon`, because the daemon may have been started when `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` was not set.

Answer (score 3):

My tests were running using surefire plugin,
If said vm argument added in argline, then test started working.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.14.1</version>
     <configuration>
       <argLine>-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true </argLine>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem building with a gradle project. A lot of VM binding issues. Adding

`JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true`

in the 'Modify Configuration' pane to environment variables did fix this. However, adding anything to 'VM options' did nothing.